# Python process.daemon = False doesn't work on Windows

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

This multiprocessing doesn't work on Windows only! It works on my Mac though.

```
p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
p.daemon = False
```

Then in the target f, I have

```
manager = Manager()
```

It says "daemonic processes are not allowed to have children". But I have set the daemon mode to be False.

Is this a bug or Windows doesn't support non-daemonic mode?

Comment: maybe the error is saying your caller is daemonic? wild guess.

Comment: The caller is __main__.